# Play framework 2.2.2 project link to see/download sample application other than plays officials project

Tags: java, mysql, playframework-2.2

i m new to play framework and web development, can any one send me link of play framework app that contains drop down list,file upload,calender and any other code(java).thank you

Comment: The play framework archive already contains some sample projects. If the acitivator version does not, then try the plain version: http://downloads.typesafe.com/play/2.2.2/play-2.2.2.zip. Oh you want other projects than that? Then look at github. There are some projects there.

Comment: Docs say that your installation comes with sample projects: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Samples . So check out the samples/ directory?

Comment: @tom and ..thank you.. i have checked play's sample project before..i need some advanced project like showing year and month and some events associate with it..

Comment: @software you should check the zentaks sample project for the date thing. Ecspecially the template taks/item.scala.html, it contains date formating. It may also help you with other questions. (`@task.dueDate.format("MMM dd yyyy")`)